# Pandoc - empty space around image

Tags: pandoc

I'm workign on a markdown document which is converted to pdf with Pandoc. I struggle with annoying png image - Pandoc consistently puts it on separate page, leaving plenty of space with no text above and below it.

Is there a setting / code I could use to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Pandoc treats images as figures if the image is the only element in a paragraph. You can prevent that by adding an HTML comment, e.g.

```markdown
![My image](path/to/image.png)<!-- not a figure -->
```

This will make sure that the image is placed right where it is in the source and not moved around. Of course, there also won't be any figure caption when doing this, but it doesn't sound as this is an issue for you.

Comment: thank you tarleb. Sadly getting rid of figure caption is an issue. I need it :/ - and I need to generate lof and lot later on. Thus straight inline image wouldn't work in my use case.